# Make a table row span multiple columns using kable and kableExtra

Tags: html, r, html-table, kable, kableextra

I am trying to create an HTML table using R and the `kable` and `kableExtra` packages. I am having problems creating a row that spans several columns. I want to create a table where the last row contains the same values for all the columns without actually repeating this value. I've created a small example of what I am trying to do below.

```
library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)

summary_stats <- matrix(c(51,43,22,22),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
colnames(summary_stats) <- c("Mean","SD")
rownames(summary_stats) <- c("Age","Observations")
summary_stats

kable_table <- kable(summary_stats) %>% 
  kable_styling()
```

Instead of repeating the number 22 on the last row for the two columns, I'd like to center it between the two columns.

I am able to achieve what I want with the following HTML code using the `colspan` argument:

```
<table class="table" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th style="text-align:left;">   </th>
   <th style="text-align:right;"> Mean </th>
   <th style="text-align:right;"> SD </th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
   <td style="text-align:left;"> Age </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 51 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 43 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="text-align:left;"> Observations </td>
   <td style="text-align:center;" colspan =  "2"> 22 </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Note that the HTML code is just the output of the `kable_table` object I created in R where I've manually edited the HTML code to include the colspan argument. I would like to do this programmatically within R instead of having to manually change the code.

I've tried to use the `row_spec` function from the `kableExtra` package to add the necessary code but I am limited by the fact that the `add_css` option (as expected) only accepts arguments related to styling. In other words, I cannot pass the `colspan` argument to the option.

My question is if there is a reasonable way of adding the necessary HTML to the table after I've created it or if there is any option within the kable/kabeExtra framework that allows me to do this that I've missed?

Answer (score 0):

Older question, but as I needed this and figured it out, here we go anyway.

Idea is to use `xml2` package as it makes this vastly easier.

Procedure is that you save kable object as xml, add rowspan attribute to cells, and remove cells that are not needed

```r
library(dplyr)
library(kable)
library(kableExtra)
library(xml2)

df <- iris[c(1:5, 51:55, 101:105), ]
df <- df[, c(1,2,5,3,4)] # moved column Species in 3rd place for easier following of example
rownames(df) <- NULL # remove rownames as xml2 uses them as first column
k_xml <- kable(df) %>%
  kableExtra::kable_styling(full_width = F) %>%
  kable_as_xml()

# I have a pattern and therefore I can repeat which value spans from where to where
# hence using for loop. These can also be assigned manually for each row

for(i in 0:2){
  # add attribute
  k_xml %>%
    xml_child(2) %>% # body
    xml_child(i*5+1) %>% # rows 1, 6 or 11
    xml_child(3) %>% # Species column
    xml_set_attr("rowspan", "5") # spans 5 rows
  
  ### PLACEHOLDER ###
  
  for(j in c(2:5)){
    # remove cells from other 4 rows
    k_xml %>%
      xml_child(2) %>% # body
      xml_child(i*5+j) %>% # other rows
      xml_child(3) %>% # Species column
      xml_remove()
  }
}

xml_as_kable(k_xml)
```

If you would also want to rotate and center those cells, insert in place of `### PLACEHOLDER ###` following code, wrapping the cell in `div` and `span`, setting class and styling:

```r
k_xml %>%
  xml_child(2) %>% # body
  xml_child(i*5+1) %>% # rows 1, 6 or 11
  xml_child(3) %>% # Species column
  xml_contents() %>%
  xml_add_parent("div") # create div around it
k_xml %>%
  xml_child(2) %>% # body
  xml_child(i*5+1) %>% # rows 1, 6 or 11
  xml_child(3) %>% # Species column
  xml_child(1) %>% # new div
  xml_set_attr("class", "rotate-cell") # set class
k_xml %>%
  xml_child(2) %>% # body
  xml_child(i*5+1) %>% # rows 1, 6 or 11
  xml_child(3) %>% # Species column
  xml_child(1) %>% # new div
  xml_contents() %>%
  xml_add_parent("span") # create span inside div
k_xml %>%
  xml_child(2) %>% # body
  xml_child(i*5+1) %>% # rows 1, 6 or 11
  xml_child(3) %>% # Species column
  xml_set_attr("style", "vertical-align:middle; text-align:center;") # styling of td
```

And add following code to your css file or css chunk:

```css
td > div.rotate-cell {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```

If you dont have any, create css chunk at the beginning

````css
```{css, echo=FALSE}
td > div.rotate-cell {   
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```
````